# How can i draw on a canvas in mobile device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

i have some canvases in my code. All of these are like a blackboard, this canvases let me draw on an image, but when i try to draw in a device nothing happens. This is all of my code:

```js
let configureCanvas = canvas => {
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  let painting = canvas.parentNode;
  let paintStyle = getComputedStyle(painting);


  if(canvas == document.getElementById("pizarra-musculos")) {
      var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)")
      myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
      x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes 
      function myFunction(x) {
      if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
          canvas.width = "350";
          canvas.height = "350";
        } else {
          canvas.width = "500";
          canvas.height = "500";
        }
      }
  }else{
    canvas.width = "350";
    canvas.height = "350";
  }


  let mouse = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };

  canvas.ontouchstart = function(e){
    var touches = e.touches || [];
    var touch = touches[0] || {};
  }

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop
  }, false);

  if(canvas == document.getElementById("pizarra-musculos")) {
     //Rojo Claro
    ctx.lineWidth = 12;
    ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255, 8, 53, 0.02)';

    document.getElementById("btnRojoClaro").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
      //Rojo Claro
      ctx.lineWidth = 12;
      ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
      ctx.lineCap = 'round';
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255, 8, 53, 0.02)';
    });
    document.getElementById("btnVerde").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
      //Rojo Claro
      ctx.lineWidth = 4;
      ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
      ctx.lineCap = 'round';
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#249120';
    });
    document.getElementById("btnRojo").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
      //Rojo Claro
      ctx.lineWidth = 4;
      ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
      ctx.lineCap = 'round';
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
    });
    document.getElementById("btnNegro").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
      //Negro
      ctx.lineWidth = 4;
      ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
      ctx.lineCap = 'round';
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    });
    document.getElementById("btnAzul").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
      //Azul
      ctx.lineWidth = 4;
      ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
      ctx.lineCap = 'round';
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#1e5085';
    });


  }else{
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
   ctx.strokeStyle = '#e34f54';
  };

  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
  }, false);

  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false)
  }, false);

  var onPaint = function() {
    ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    ctx.stroke();
  };

  canvas.nextElementSibling.addEventListener('click', function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  });


}
```

PD: i learned about the touchscreens on mozila developers but i can't do functionally this canvas on device... Thanks for learning my question.

Comment: Can't even draw on PC in that snippet

Comment: @Samathingamajig What do you mean? i can draw in pc

Comment: When I click "Rune code snippet", and attempt to draw, nothing happens

Comment: Oh yes because it need the html part to work... But i need to get the event on touch and draw de canvas in mobile not in desktop

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, you can add listenner! That means that something will be listenned and a code will be executed when the listenner will be activated !

For instance, if you declare in html `<button id="mybutton"></button>` in js, you can retrieve this button with `document.getElementById("mybutton")`, thus, you can manipulate the element itself, value, return, action, etc...,

Let's store this element `var button = document.getElementById("mybutton")`
now `console.log(button)` will sort of display this element, cool right ?

On this button you can add listenner, onClick for example that will execute a function when the button is clicked
`button.addEvenListenner("onClick", my_function)`

So now when you will click on your button you will execute my_function (you need to create my_function of course)

But in your case your want to get the eventListenner of a mouse mouve or when someone use finger on their phone!

You already made it, with 'mousemove' for example ! or 'mouseup' etc...
The thing desktop is a phone and vice versa!
You don't have a mouse on your phone you have your finger, so need to have a listenner when someone touch de screen!

That's where 'touchstart' event listenner is here for, when you touch the screen, you can call a function to do whatever you want with this !

Those four listenner will be enough for your project, why you may ask ?
'touchstart' tells when you touch the screen
'touchend' tells when you remove your finger from the screen
'touchmove' tells when you drag your finger on the screen (touchstart and touchmove are not the same thing !)
'touchcancel' tells when you cancel (Honestly I don't know, you don't need it I guess)

now you need to add your listenner to your canvas

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("pizarra-musculos")
```

then you add your listenner

```
  canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart);
  canvas.addEventListener("touchend", handleEnd);
  canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", handleMove);
```

Now when one of those 3 listenner will be used, the function next to them will be called !
Thus, you can execute whatever you want in those function

```
 function handleMove(e) {
      // Cache the client X/Y coordinates
      var clientX = e.touches[0].clientX;
      var clientY = e.touches[0].clientY;
    }
```

With this bit of code you are able to keep track of the x and y of your finger of your screen, try every listenner to know when they are called etc.. put some console.log to print out value, you will do it it's not hard hope it helped you

Comment: Hey @nerap, thanks for your response... but i'm a noob in the field of canvas and js, can you explain more detailed for me?